# standard-version - Avoid link on CHANGELOG.md

Tags: git, npm, changelog

I'm starting to use standard-version to generate CHANGELOG.md for my project

I've added a .versionrc file that looks like this:

```
{
"bumpFiles": [
    {
        "filename": "version.txt",
        "type": "plain-text"
    },
    {
        "filename": "package.json",
        "type": "json"
    }
],
"header": "My CHANGELOG header",
"types": [
    { "type": "feat", "section": "Features" },
    { "type": "fix", "section": "Bug Fixes" },
    { "type": "chore", "hidden": true },
    { "type": "docs", "hidden": true },
    { "type": "style", "hidden": true },
    { "type": "refactor", "hidden": true },
    { "type": "perf", "hidden": true },
    { "type": "test", "hidden": true }
],
"commitUrlFormat": null, //custom try to avoid commit url link
"compareUrlFormat": ""   //custom try to avoid commit compare url link
}
```

My goal is to avoid creating link to commit or commit comparison at every entry of my CHANGELOG.md.

I can edit link url with [Substitutions](https://github.com/conventional-changelog/conventional-changelog-config-spec/blob/master/versions/2.1.0/README.md#substitutions-1) functionality but i don't know how to produce changelog entries without any link.

So far I have tried "" and null, like the two `commitUrlFormat` and `compareUrlFormat` attribute on my example but neither gave the desired result, any suggestion is welcome